# Column.Expression = String(1)

Tags: vb.net, datatable, linq-expressions, datacolumn

In my DataTable I have one column that is :

```
With colA
            .DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")
            .ColumnName = "colA"
End With
```

I have an array of strings named strTest and strTest(6) is "00".

I try to do that :

```
colA.Expression = strTest(6)
```

No error, but in place of set the value to "00" it writes "0".

Where is my mistake ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's evaluating your expression as a constant number.  Instead, use single quotes and it'll know its a string.:

```
colA.Expression = "'" & strTest(6) & "'"
```

Comment: thank you, I made the correction and this is working.